# What are the main differences between P4 and P4 Golden?

Tags: persona-4-golden

Since there's the rerelease of P5 as P5 : The Royale in a few months, I would like to know what were the differences between the main game and it's rerelease in the previous opus: P4.

So what are the differences between P4 and P4 Golden? Is it the same game just with an additional character/dungeon or is it a very different story?

Comment: I'm not sure of all the differences but one main one which you note is that there is a new Character who comes with their own Social Link and Dungeon, the plot is mostly the same from my understanding except with the added bits for this new character (ie. even if you ignore this character you'll get a slight reference to them near the end but the end is still the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Megami Tensei Wiki](https://megamitensei.fandom.com/wiki/Persona_4_Golden):

- Aeon and Jester/Hunger Arcana return (including summonable Personas).
- A new character, Marie, introducing a new S-Link (Aeon Arcana). Completing the S-Link before December 23 unlocks a new dungeon. Completing it unlocks a new epilogue.
- Another new S-Link (Jester/Hunger Arcana) tied to Tohru Adachi. Along with it, there's a new bad end (Accomplice Ending).
- New epilogue for True Ending.
- New difficulties, including Safety (Very Easy) and Risky (Very Hard).
- New music tracks.
- Additional voice-over dialogue.
- Chie and Teddy have new English voices.
- New animated cutscenes.
- More Personas, including Ultimate Personas for each member of the Investigation Team (if you've completed their S-Link).
- New areas, such as Shichiri Beach, and a ski resort. Additionally, you can now visit Okina City (previously limited to S-Link scenes). The Investigation Team has now access to scooters to visit some of these areas.
- New events, such as Halloween and a skiing trip.
- You can now explore (some parts of) the town at night, as long as Dojima isn't home.
- Can buy costumes in Okina City. Costumes only affect appearance and do not interfere with your usual equipment.
- New Garden and Bug Catching features.
- Trophies (obviously).
- When fusing Personas, the inherited skills are no longer random (you can choose which to carry over, within limitations).
- Vox Populi (online mode similar to the one in Persona 5 or Fire Emblem Three Houses).
- Scenes can now be skipped.
- If you have fulfilled the conditions for the good ending, you can keep playing until February 14, giving you more time to complete S-Links.
- Changes to requests made by NPCs or the fox.
- Several changes to battles, including rebalancing, Rise assisting in All-Out-Attacks, Tag Team Attacks (e.g. Chie & Yukiko's "Twin Dragon" attack), Cavalry Attacks (attacks from someone not in the current active team), and increasing the duration of buffs and debuffs by casting them on targets that are already affected by the same buff or debuff.
- "TV Listing" feature, where bonus contents can be accessed, including replays of cutscenes.
- Floors and chests reset by changing floor instead of changing dungeon or leaving the TV world.

Comment: So mostly a character+dungeon with some scenes changed to make that character fit in the story. That + some bonus features.

Comment: Choosing inherited skills when fusing Personae feels like it could be pretty significant.